# What happened to Ambient Occlusion?

Tags: compositing-nodes, world

Ambient Occlusion used to be under World Properties. Where is it now to find?

Answer (score 7):

Ambient Occlusion is only in World properties when you're using Cycles prior to 3.x.  For EEVEE it's in Render properties, and for Cycles X (3.0 and later Cycles)  it is a pass in the Light Tab of the View Layers property.